# get meta description tag with xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I need the content the description and the keywords tag content. I have this code, but dont write anything. Idea?

```
$str = <<< EOD

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

<meta name="description" content="text in the description tag" />

<meta name="keywords" content="text, in, the, keywords, tag" />

</head>

EOD;
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($str);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('/html/head/meta[name="description"]');

foreach($nodes as $node){
  print $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can reference the attributes using `@` followed by the attribute name (see below), and you can query directly for the attributes; your XPath query was almost there.

```
// Look for the content attribute of description meta tags 
$contents = $xpath->query('/html/head/meta[@name="description"]/@content');

// If nothing matches the query
if ($contents->length == 0) {
    echo "No description meta tag :(";
// Found one or more descriptions, loop over them
} else {
    foreach ($contents as $content) {
        echo $content->value . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems. First, name is an attribute so you need to prepend @,

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('/html/head/meta[@name="description"]');
```

Second, the nodes are all empty so there is nothing to print.

To print the attribute value, do this,

```
foreach($nodes as $node){
  $attr = $node->getAttribute('content');
  print $attr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In stead of including the /html/head part you could also use double slash which means that the following node can be anywhere in the code:

```
//meta[@name='description']
```

Will give the same result as:

```
/html/head/meta[@name='description']
```

Doesn't really matter much but it's less typing...

Answer (score 1):

Last but not least, and sorry for reviving this thread, **the queries are case sensitive.**

In other words, if you look for meta name="description"... or  "meta name="keywords", it will not find  "meta name="Description"... or  "meta name="Keywords"... respectively. So careful with that!

And I can tell you, after working a while with xdom and metatags, eventually I believe that the best approach for that is to use this function: http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-meta-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you put `EOD;` at a line without any spaces and indentation like:

```
  $str = <<< EOD
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

EOD;
```