# xpath query giving no result

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I am trying to change/update meta description from dom for one of my page on fly. So I tried following way,

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //I'm not sure this is helpful
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 
$name = 'desciption';
$query = '/html/head/meta[@name=\''.$name.'\']/@content';
$contents = $xpath->query($query);
echo $contents->item(0)->value; //blank :(
```

Here I'm unable to get the content value for meta description.

- I checked `htmlspecialchars($dom)` & it's seems correct.
- I checked view-source of page & desciption is in the html->head->meta
  tag ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/i4ZS0fkb) of page head tag).

Anyone can help me out what can be the issue here ? Is anything wrong with my query ?

Comment: I think you should concatenate $name with double quotes since it should be `@name="description"`, also remove the slashes in the name attribute. `$query = '/html/head/meta[@name='."$name".']/@content';`

Comment: No luck. Tried with both single & double quotes, still no output. This is my query `/html/head/meta[@name="description"]/@content`.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907478/get-meta-description-tag-with-xpath

Comment: works for me, let me post an example

Comment: Yes, I checked that question & using query exactly same way. I'm not sure what is wrong in my case. May be dom structure ?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but, meta tags aren't closed properly on page...

Comment: Well, I answered, but I think I got question - how do you link the query to your HTML page, do you have DOMDocument object? The $dom variable should be instance of it, but is it?

Comment: Unclosed meta tags are problem, def, now i tested it again... With properly closed tags - all works fine, otherwise: Trying to get property of non-object error appears.

Comment: I tried with both of the html's given, and have no problem, which tag is not properly closed

Comment: @nevermind - I don't think, I have just posted a snippet of my head code.

Comment: @RoyalBg - Yes, it is a dom object. And same code is working fine for other pages. But not for this.

Comment: working with `/html/head/meta[@name="description"]/@content` but when i use the `$name` variable its just not working :\ weird

Comment: @Rikesh, yes i know - but i mean on meta tags... really strange... :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me, when the alue is quotes by double quotes, let's post an example, since it doesn't get clear in the comment.

I created a file `html.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="some content">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and then a php:

```
<?php
$file = "html.html";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($file);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 
$name = 'description';
$query = '/html/head/meta[@name="'.$name.'"]/@content';
$contents = $xpath->query($query);
echo $contents->item(0)->value;
?>
```

And the output is `some content`

You need to close the single quotes after the first double ones, so they will be kept in the quoted string, then to put the variable, start quoting and put double quotes again

EDIT:

I have used your HTML from the posted site:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
<!--
#qm0 {position:relative;}
                    #qm0 a {display:block; white-space:nowrap; }
                    #qm0 div a {float:none;}
                    #qm0 div {visibility:hidden;position:absolute;}
                    #qm0 a {float: left; }
-->
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Product1 Name</title>
<link href="n-defaultStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta name="keywords" content=" Ilmfpnv, VrbfZgj, Fsikeprr Mluw">
<meta name="description" content="Beu Urb Hcsmihnurb cl c avlqclb ZtatcZq nrbc in unidrdpt cft mbvfp kj rmi isspulu. Uqwoiab in sf upq lkspuj jZ oed diirovs">
</head>
```

And still have no problems, output:

`Beu Urb Hcsmihnurb cl c avlqclb ZtatcZq nrbc in unidrdpt cft mbvfp kj rmi isspulu. Uqwoiab in sf upq lkspuj jZ oed diirovs`