# Retrieve a meta with the same name with get_meta_tags() function

Tags: php, wordpress, get-meta-tags

I'm trying to retrieve the `<meta name="generator">` of a web page with the php [get_meta_tags()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.get-meta-tags.php) function.

Worry is that my web page contains TWO same meta :

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 5.9.3">
<meta name="generator" content="Site Kit by Google 1.73.0">
```

And `get_meta_tags()` seems to only want to retrieve the last when **I want the first**.

Here is my code :

```
$fullURL = 'https://thibautchourre.com/';
$metas = get_meta_tags($fullURL);
$versionwp = $metas['generator']
echo $versionwp
```

An idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`get_meta_tags`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) function only returns the last element when the name is duplicated.

> If two meta tags have the same name, only the last one is returned

You could use a parser to get all `meta` elements.

Sample:

```
<?php
$html = '<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 5.9.3">
<meta name="generator" content="Site Kit by Google 1.73.0">
';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
foreach($metas as $meta){
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'generator'){
        echo $meta->getAttribute('content') . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/jDeNo

Alternative using xpath, (adapt from [get meta description tag with xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907478/get-meta-description-tag-with-xpath))

```
$html = '<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 5.9.3">
<meta name="generator" content="Site Kit by Google 1.73.0">
';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//meta[@name="generator"]/@content');
foreach($nodes as $node){
    echo $node->textContent . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `get_meta_tags` is returning an array and you can't have duplicate array keys.