# Parse Meta Tags PHP

Tags: php, html, meta-tags

I have this code on my html page:

```
<header class="adPage__header">
    <h1 itemprop="name">BMW 3 Series</h1>
</header>
<ul class="adPage__content__price-feature__prices">
    <li class=" adPage__content__price-feature__prices__price is-main "> 
        <span class="adPage__content__price-feature__prices__price__value" itemprop="price" content="2850"> 2 850 </span>
        <span class="adPage__content__price-feature__prices__price__currency" itemprop="priceCurrency" content="€"> € </span> 
   </li>
</ul>
```

How I can parse them into my php code?
I tried like this:

```
$ec = file_get_contents($text);
  preg_match("/(?<=itemprop=\"price\"\ content=\").*?(?=\ €)/",$ec,$matches_price);
  preg_match("/(?<=h1=\"itemprop=\"\ name\">).*?(?=\ )/",$ec,$matches_nazv);
  preg_match("/(?<=src=\").*?(?=\"\ alt)/",$ec,$matches_photo);
```

Thx for help!

Comment: Where are the meta tags? Here's an answer I have previously about parsing meta tags, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72063836/retrieve-a-meta-with-the-same-name-with-get-meta-tags-function/72063872#72063872

Comment: The code you've shown does not contain any meta tags. Also, why not use any DOM parser for your problem?